# TFS 2010 API - Copy/clone build definitions with process parameter values

Tags: tfs, build-definition

I'm using the TFS API for copying buildefinitins. However I am not able to copy build process template paramaters with values. I can't see the values in an IBuildDefinition object. Where can i fetch the values and clone them as well?

My starting point is [How can I copy a TFS 2010 Build Definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909416/how-can-i-copy-a-tfs-2010-build-definition) .

The line

```
buildDefinitionClone.ProcessParameters = buildDefinition.ProcessParameters;
```

copies the process parameters, but not all the other custom values that I set in the build definition

Answer (score 0):

Before this line did you copy the template also. If not then use this line - 
buildDefinitionClone.Process = buildDefinition.Process;